# js, prototype = other prototype is legal?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

hi is it legal to reference a method, prototypes like this way.

```
animationControler_Actors.prototype.addMotionContext_linear = animationControler_Pictures.prototype.addMotionContext_linear; // compatibility with Actor Module
animationControler_Events.prototype.addMotionContext_linear = animationControler_Pictures.prototype.addMotionContext_linear; // compatibility with Events Module
```

I want to avoid duplicating the code that will be identical, so I assign it this way.

thanks
(SOLVED CLOSE)

Comment: Sure, it's no different than assigning any other function reference

Comment: thank you, I doubted and I was not sure.
and not find any information about this kind of assignation.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is illegal but why not put the function in a module of its own and import it from there?  This could definitely be confusing for the next guy.

Comment: this is not a bad idea, thank you for the suggestion.